# Opening vs2010 C# project in vs2015 resulting in error in designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-designer

I can access the code but can not open the designer view. I can add new items and code them, only the existing item's designer view is returning these errors.

I can also run and debug the program successfully.

The only problem is that now that I have opened it on vs2015, it  can not be opened in vs2010 again.

I have been Googling for hours and tried all sorts of things, but still no luck.

**Stack trace:**

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.Exceptions.ThrowEFail()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.LookupTypeSymbol()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.GetUrtTypeFromVsType(CodeTypeRef vsType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnTypePopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationPopulator.OnPopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Comment: Backwards compatibility in project files only works from VS 2012 and on.  I believe when it converts the project file to the new format it makes a backup of the old project file.  Check for a backup folder in with the project.